# How can I fix _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry" error with Python-Requests API in my Tkinter code?

Tags: python, api, tkinter, python-requests

This is the error I'm getting:

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"
```

I expect someone to enter the state in entry and in my code I get that string, send it to http://universities.hipolabs.com/search, and get the result. However, I'm getting the error above. If I get the name of the state with `input()` the code works.

```
import tkinter as tk
window=tk.Tk()
# window.iconbitmap("icon\ico3\hp_download.ico")
window.title("Universitis Of IRAN")
# w,h=window.winfo_screenwidth(),window.winfo_screenheight()
# window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(w,h,0,0))
window.geometry('400x400')
def show(event):
    root=tk.Tk()
    def func(e):
        print(type(province.get()))
        # root.destroy()
    Button=tk.Button(root,text="Return",width=30)
    Button.bind("<Button>",func)
    Button.grid(row=2,column=2)
    root.mainloop()
label=tk.Label(window,text=" Enter the province : ",width=30)
province=tk.Entry(window,width=30)
showButton=tk.Button(window,text="Show",width=30)
showButton.bind("<Button>",show)
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
province.grid(row=0,column=1)
showButton.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()

import requests,json
land={'country':'IRAN'}
res=requests.get('http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?',land)
if res.status_code==200:
    temp=res.json()
    stateStr=province.get()
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        if temp[i]["state-province"]==stateStr:
            print(temp[i]["name"])
            print("web address : ",temp[i]["web_pages"])
        else:
            print('no')
    

else:
    print('not found')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `Entry` object province after the main `tkinter` loop has ended, then all the widgets get cleaned up and can't be accessed.

Lets try to send the request and process the result within the scope of the `Tkinter` main loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import json

def show():
    res = requests.get('http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?', {'country': 'IRAN'})
    if res.status_code == 200:
        temp = res.json()
        stateStr = province.get()
        for i in range(len(temp)):
            if temp[i]["state-province"] == stateStr:
                print(temp[i]["name"])
                print("web address : ", temp[i]["web_pages"])
            else:
                print('no')
    else:
        print('not found')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Universities Of IRAN")
window.geometry('400x400')

label = tk.Label(window,text="Enter the province : ",width=30)
province = tk.Entry(window,width=30)
showButton = tk.Button(window, text="Show", command=show, width=30)

label.grid(row=0, column=0)
province.grid(row=0, column=1)
showButton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```